# Why same smart contract deployed multiple time by same creator address?

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, etherscan

I an doing a case study in which i need to find the source code differences in multiple smart contracts deployed by same creator address. During this I find that multiple smart contract (number exceed to 1000) with exact same name and source code without any slightest change deployed by same address with minor time difference. Is there any reason why the one address deployed this much instances of same smart contract?

Answer (score 2):

There might be many reasons for it.

One obvious one might be that you have quite some factory contracts that deploy contract instances, that just differentiate in state (e.g. owners).

An example for such factory contract is the [GnosisSafeProxyFactory](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa6B71E26C5e0845f74c812102Ca7114b6a896AB2#code) which creates the same proxy for all users and just changes the configuration which is stored in the storage.

There are such contracts also for token contracts that enable different use cases (e.g. token bridges which create bridged token wrappers or token wrappers between different token standards).